# Create multiple XmlDocument objects based on the number of XML files in a directory

Tags: c#, xml

I have multiple XML files in a directory, Each directory you can consider as each scenario. Based on the business scenario number of XML files may differ in a directory.

From the Below code I got total number of files.

```
string tempPath = rootPath+"/Templates"; // Template directory path
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@tempPath);
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.xml"); // getting all file names
```

Am trying to set the namespace for the xml like the below code

```
//Setting namespace for each xml

foreach(FileInfo file in files)
{
    var tempXml = file.Name;
    XmlDocument tempXml = new XmlDocument();
    tempXml.Load(tempPath+"/"+file.Name);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(tempXml.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("imp", namespace1); // namespace1 value I took it from excel
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"); 
}
```

Later that I trying to insert value in the xml doc like this

```
XmlNode businessContactNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode(xPath,nsMgr);
```

The above code is not working and I know am doing some serious mistake in the code. Am new to this C# code, Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It is not clear from the code what problems are you facing or what is the final objective. What exceptions are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FOLDER = @"\c:\temp";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER);
            foreach (string file in filenames)
            {
                XDocument tempXml = XDocument.Load(file);
                XElement root = (XElement)tempXml.FirstNode;
                XNamespace  nsMgr = root.Name.Namespace;

                XElement node = root.Descendants(nsMgr + "TagName").FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }
    }
}
```